# using subversion with netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: svn, netbeans

We have `VisualSVN Server` in our local network. I want to work with this svn server in order to control versioning of my java projects.
I use `Netbeans 7.3.1` IDE and my PC is running on `Windows XP SP3`. I read that `7.3.1` already has subversion support.(Menu/Team/Subverion)
I want to know  how to add my project to `VisualSVN Server` as a repository. Do i need to install any subversion client software like `TortoiseSVN` or `CollabNet`? If yes, which one should i install and how?
I am alittle bit confused, can you give me some instructions about where i can start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, your repository already exists. Then, the main steps are:

1. Check if the "Subversion" plugin is installed. If not, install it (Tools/Plugins/Available Plugins/Subversion).
2. Right-click on the name of your project, select "Versioning" and "Import into Subversion Repository".
3. Follow the instructions in the pop-up frame.

Please, let us know if it worked.

You can get detailed information on this site: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html